# Why does my variable not flip accordingly?

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

The Button named 'ft' is supposed to take the current Boolean state of a value and if it's True 'on' make it False 'off' and delete a red line, Or if it's False 'off' make it True 'on' and re-create the red line. For some reason this only works the first two times i push the Button then it stops working and i can not figure out why

```
   import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
state="on"
def nothing():
    print ("meh.")
def controller(canvas,redline,test):
    def something(canvas, redline, state):
        if state=="off":
            state="on"
            redline=canvas.create_line(0,100,200,50, fill="red")
            print ("state=off", state)
            return state
        else:
            state="off"
            canvas.delete(redline)
            print ("state=on",state)
            return state
    state=something(canvas, redline, test)
    global state
root=Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
blackline=canvas.create_line(0,0,200,50)
redline=canvas.create_line(0,100,200,50, fill="red")
greenline=canvas.create_line(0,50,200,50, fill="green")

toolbar=Frame(root, bg="red")
ft=Button(toolbar, text="TEST", command=lambda:controller(canvas,redline,state))
ft.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have two variables `redline`, one (local) inside `controller`, and second (global) outside this function. You don't assign new value to external/global value when you create again this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables `redline`, one (local) inside controller, and second (global) outside this function. You don't assign new value to external/global value when you create again this line. You have to use `global redline` inside function

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

# --- functions ---

def nothing():
    print ("meh.")

def controller():
    global state
    global redline

    if state:
        canvas.delete(redline)
    else:
        redline = canvas.create_line(0, 100, 200, 50, fill="red")

    state = not state
    print("state:", state)

# --- main ---

state = True

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
blackline = canvas.create_line(0, 0, 200, 50)
redline = canvas.create_line(0, 100, 200, 50, fill="red")
greenline = canvas.create_line(0, 50, 200, 50, fill="green")

toolbar = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")

ft = tk.Button(toolbar, text="TEST", command=controller)

ft.pack(side='left', padx=2, pady=2)
toolbar.pack(side='top', fill='x')

canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```